# Non UTF-8 compliant character "\x{0D}" at the end of output csv rows

Tags: python, csv, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a very frustrating problem that I don't know how to solve. The following Python script processes a bunch of XML documents from a directory and it extracts information from them. With that information, it creates a csv file.

```
import re
import time
import csv
from lxml import etree as et
from pathlib import Path
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from tqdm import tqdm
import ftfy


st = time.time()

XMLDIR = Path('/Users/josepm.fontana/Downloads/CICA_CORPUS_XML_CLEAN')
files = [e for e in XMLDIR.iterdir() if e.is_file()]
xml_doc = [f for f in files if f.with_suffix(".xml")]
myCSV_FILE = "/Volumes/SanDisk1TB/_CORPUS_WORK/CSVs/TestDataSet19-6-23_YZh.csv"
time_log = Path(
    '/Volumes/SanDisk1TB/_CORPUS_WORK/TEXT_FILES/log_time_pathlib.txt')
results = Path(
    '/Volumes/SanDisk1TB/_CORPUS_WORK/TEXT_FILES/TestDataSet19-6-23_YZh.txt')


tok_path = et.XPath('//tok | //dtok')


def xml_extract(xml_doc):

    root_element = et.parse(xml_doc).getroot()
    autor = None
    data = None
    tipus = None
    dialecte = None

    header = root_element.find("header")
    if header is not None:
        for el in header:

            if el.get("type") == "autor":
                autor = el.text
                autor = ftfy.fix_text(autor)
            elif el.get("type") == "data":
                data = el.text
                data = ftfy.fix_text(data)
            elif el.get("type") == "tipologia":
                tipus = el.text
                tipus = ftfy.fix_text(tipus)
            elif el.get("type") == "dialecte":
                dialecte = el.text
                dialecte = ftfy.fix_text(dialecte)


    all_toks = tok_path(root_element)

    matching_toks = filter(lambda tok: tok.get('xpos') is not None and tok.get(
        'xpos').startswith('A') and not (tok.get('xpos').startswith('AX')), all_toks)

    for el in matching_toks:
        preceding_tok = el.xpath(
            "./preceding-sibling::tok[1][@lemma and @xpos]")
        preceding_tok_with_dtoks = el.xpath(
            "./preceding-sibling::tok[1][not(@lemma) and not(@xpos)]"
        )
        following_dtok_of_dtok = el.xpath("./preceding-sibling::dtok[1]")

        if el.tag == 'tok':
            tok_dtok = 'tok'
            Adj = "".join(el.itertext())
            Adj_lemma = el.get('lemma')
            Adj_xpos = el.get('xpos')
            Adj = ftfy.fix_text(Adj)

        elif el.tag == 'dtok':
            tok_dtok = 'dtok'
            Adj = el.get('form')
            Adj_lemma = el.get('lemma')
            Adj_xpos = el.get('xpos')
            Adj = ftfy.fix_text(Adj)

        pos = all_toks.index(el)

        RelevantPrecedingElements = all_toks[max(pos - 6, 0):pos]

        RelevantFollowingElements = all_toks[pos + 1:max(pos + 6, 1)]
        
        
        if RelevantPrecedingElements:
            
            prec1 = RelevantPrecedingElements[-1]
        else:
            prec1 = None

        if RelevantFollowingElements:
            foll1 = RelevantFollowingElements[0]
        else:
            foll1 = None
        
        
        
        

        ElementsContext = all_toks[max(pos - 6, 0):pos + 1]

        context_list = []
        
        
        
        if ElementsContext:
            for elem in ElementsContext:
                elem_text = "".join(elem.itertext())
                assert elem_text is not None
                context_list.append(elem_text)

        Adj = f"<{Adj}>"

        for elem in RelevantFollowingElements:
            elem_text = "".join(elem.itertext())
            assert elem_text is not None
            context_list.append(elem_text)

        fol_lem = foll1.get('lemma') if foll1 is not None else None
        prec_lem = prec1.get('lemma') if prec1 is not None else None
        fol_xpos = foll1.get('xpos') if foll1 is not None else None
        prec_xpos = prec1.get('xpos') if prec1 is not None else None
        
        
        fol_form = None
        if foll1 is not None:
            if foll1.tag == "tok":
                fol_form = foll1.text
            elif foll1.tag == "dtok":
                fol_form = foll1.get("form")
            
        prec_form = None
        if prec1 is not None:

            if prec1.tag == "tok":
                prec_form = prec1.text
            elif prec1.tag == "dtok":
                prec_form = prec1.get("form")

        context = " ".join(context_list).replace(
            " ,", ",").replace(" .", ".").replace("   ", " ").replace("  ", " ")

        llista = [
            context,
            prec_form,
            Adj,
            fol_form,
            prec_lem,
            Adj_lemma,
            fol_lem,
            prec_xpos,
            Adj_xpos,
            fol_xpos,
            tok_dtok,
            xml_doc.name,
            autor,
            data,
            tipus,
            dialecte,
        ]

        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=";")
        writer.writerow(llista)
        with open(results, "a") as Results:
            Results.write(f"@@@ {context} @@@\n\n")
            Results.write(f"Source: {xml_doc.name}\n\n\n")


with open(myCSV_FILE, "a+", encoding="UTF8", newline='') as csv_file:




    #Parallel(n_jobs=-1,  prefer="threads")(delayed(xml_extract)(xml_doc) for xml_doc in tqdm(files))
    Parallel(n_jobs=-1, prefer="threads")(delayed(xml_extract)(xml_doc) for xml_doc in tqdm(files) if not xml_doc.name.startswith("."))

    

elapsed_time = time.time() - st

with open(
    time_log, "a"
) as Myfile:
    Myfile.write(f"\n \n The end: The whole process took {elapsed_time} \n")
```

The text file that is created is perfect UTF-8. All of the XML documents have been double checked and triple checked to make sure they are all also properly formated as UTF-8.

At the end of every row of the csv file that is created, however, there is the "\x{0D}" character.

I do not understand this at all. This script was based on the following script that creates properly formatted csv files where this problem does not occur. The main difference is that in the problematic code I introduced parallelization via the 'joblib' library because otherwise it took forever to process all those files.

```
import re
import time
import csv
from lxml import etree as et
from pathlib import Path


st = time.time()

#XMLDIR = Path('/Volumes/SanDisk1TB/_CORPUS_WORK/CICA_WORKING_NEW')
XMLDIR = Path('/Users/josepm.fontana/Downloads/CICA_CORPUS_XML_CLEAN')
files = [e for e in XMLDIR.iterdir() if e.is_file()]
xml_doc = [f for f in files if f.with_suffix(".xml")]
myCSV_FILE = "/Volumes/SanDisk1TB/_CORPUS_WORK/CSVs/clitic_context_testTEST2.csv"
time_log = Path('/Volumes/SanDisk1TB/_CORPUS_WORK/TEXT_FILES/log_time_pathlib.txt')
results = Path('/Volumes/SanDisk1TB/_CORPUS_WORK/TEXT_FILES/resultsTEST2.txt')



tok_path = et.XPath('//tok')

def xml_extract(root_element):

    all_toks = tok_path(root_element)

    matching_toks = filter(lambda tok: re.match(r'^[EeLl][LlOoAa][Ss]*$', "".join(tok.itertext())) is not None and not(tok.get('xpos').startswith('D')), all_toks)

    for el in matching_toks: 

        fake_clitic = "".join(el.itertext())
        pos = all_toks.index(el)


        RelevantPrecedingElements = all_toks[max(pos - 6, 0):pos]
        print(RelevantPrecedingElements)

        prec1 = RelevantPrecedingElements[-1]
        #foll1 = all_toks[pos + 1]



        RelevantFollowingElements = all_toks[pos + 1:max(pos + 6, 1)]
       #prec1 = RelevantFollowingElements[]
        #foll1 = all_toks[pos + 1]
        print(RelevantFollowingElements)

        foll1 = RelevantFollowingElements[0]


        context_list = []
        context_clean = []

        for elem in RelevantPrecedingElements:
            elem_text = "".join(elem.itertext())
            assert elem_text is not None
            context_list.append(elem_text)            
            context_clean.append(elem_text)

        # adjective = '<' + str(el.text) + '>'
        fake_clitic = f"<{fake_clitic}>"
        fake_clitic_clean = f"{el.text}"

        print(fake_clitic)
        context_list.append(fake_clitic)
        context_clean.append(fake_clitic_clean)

        for elem in RelevantFollowingElements:
            elem_text = "".join(elem.itertext())
            assert elem_text is not None
            context_list.append(elem_text)
            context_clean.append(elem_text)



        lema_fol = foll1.get('lemma') if foll1 is not None else None
        lema_prec = prec1.get('lemma') if prec1 is not None else None
        xpos_fol = foll1.get('xpos') if foll1 is not None else None
        xpos_prec = prec1.get('xpos') if prec1 is not None else None
        form_fol = foll1.text if foll1 is not None else None
        form_prec = prec1.text if prec1 is not None else None

        context = " ".join(context_list)
        clean_context = " ".join(context_clean).replace(" ,", ",").replace(" .", ".")
        print(f"Context is: {context}")


        llista = [
            context,
            lema_prec,
            xpos_prec,
            form_prec,
            fake_clitic,
            lema_fol,
            xpos_fol,
            form_fol,
        ]

        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=";")
        writer.writerow(llista)
        with open(
            results, "a"
        ) as Results:
            Results.write(f"@@@ {context} @@@\n\n")
            Results.write(f"{clean_context}\n\n")
            Results.write(f"Source: {xml_doc.name}\n\n\n")

with open(myCSV_FILE, "a+", encoding="UTF8", newline="") as csv_file:

    for xml_doc in files:
        if xml_doc.name.startswith("."):
            continue
        doc = xml_doc.stem # this was 
        print(doc)
        start_file_time_beforeParse = time.time()
        print(start_file_time_beforeParse)
        print(
            f"{time.time() - st} seconds after the beginning of the process I'm starting to get the root of {xml_doc.name}"
        )
        file_root = et.parse(xml_doc).getroot()
        xml_extract(file_root)
        print(
            f"I ran through {xml_doc.name} in {time.time() - start_file_time_beforeParse} seconds!"
        )
        with open(
            time_log, "a"
        ) as Myfile:
            Myfile.write("Time it took to getroot and parse ")
            Myfile.write(xml_doc.name)
            Myfile.write("\n")
            Myfile.write("Time it took to loop through the entire ")
            Myfile.write(xml_doc.name)
            Myfile.write(" is: ")
            Myfile.write(f"{time.time() - start_file_time_beforeParse} seconds!")
            Myfile.write("\n")
            Myfile.write("\n")

elapsed_time = time.time() - st


with open(
    time_log, "a"
) as Myfile:
    Myfile.write(f"\n \n The end: The whole process took {elapsed_time} \n")


print("Execution time:", elapsed_time, "seconds")
```

I would greatly appreciate any help you can offer. This is really frustrating.

Here is a link to some sample XML files like the ones I'm trying to process:

[Sample XML files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u19wewlfacfbj63/Archive.zip?dl=0)

EDIT:

Adaptation of Zach Young's script for problematic task:

```
import csv
import re
import time

from pathlib import Path

from lxml import etree as et

beg_main = time.time()

#xmls_dir = Path("./xmls")

xmls_dir = Path('/PathTo/CLEAN_COMP_TEST2')
files = [e for e in xmls_dir.iterdir() if e.is_file()]
xml_files = [f for f in files if f.with_suffix(".xml")]

csv_path = Path("/PathTo/My_Output.csv")


csv_file = open(csv_path, "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8")
writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=";")

results_path = Path("/PathTo/my_results.txt")


results = open(results_path, "w", encoding="utf-8")

times_path = Path("/PathTo/my_times.txt")
times = open(times_path, "w", encoding="utf-8")

tok_path = et.XPath('//tok | //dtok')

def xml_extract(doc_root, fname: str):
    all_toks = tok_path(doc_root)    
    
    matching_toks = filter(
        lambda tok: 
            tok.get('xpos') is not None and tok.get
            (
        'xpos').startswith('A') and not (tok.get('xpos').startswith('AX')
        ), 
        all_toks
        )
    
    for el in matching_toks:
        preceding_tok = el.xpath(
            "./preceding-sibling::tok[1][@lemma and @xpos]")
        preceding_tok_with_dtoks = el.xpath(
            "./preceding-sibling::tok[1][not(@lemma) and not(@xpos)]"
        )
        following_dtok_of_dtok = el.xpath("./preceding-sibling::dtok[1]")

        if el.tag == 'tok':
            tok_dtok = 'tok'
            Adj = "".join(el.itertext())
            Adj_lemma = el.get('lemma')
            Adj_xpos = el.get('xpos')

        elif el.tag == 'dtok':
            tok_dtok = 'dtok'
            Adj = el.get('form')
            Adj_lemma = el.get('lemma')
            Adj_xpos = el.get('xpos')

        pos = all_toks.index(el)

        RelevantPrecedingElements = all_toks[max(pos - 6, 0):pos]

        RelevantFollowingElements = all_toks[pos + 1:max(pos + 6, 1)]

        
        if RelevantPrecedingElements:
            
            prec1 = RelevantPrecedingElements[-1]
        else:
            prec1 = None

        if RelevantFollowingElements:
            foll1 = RelevantFollowingElements[0]
        else:
            foll1 = None

                
        ElementsContext = all_toks[max(pos - 6, 0):pos + 1]


        context_list = []
        
        if ElementsContext:
            for elem in ElementsContext:
                elem_text = "".join(elem.itertext())
                assert elem_text is not None
                context_list.append(elem_text)



   
        
        Adj = f"<{Adj}>"

        

        for elem in RelevantFollowingElements:
            elem_text = "".join(elem.itertext())
            assert elem_text is not None
            context_list.append(elem_text)


        fol_lem = foll1.get('lemma') if foll1 is not None else None
        prec_lem = prec1.get('lemma') if prec1 is not None else None
        fol_xpos = foll1.get('xpos') if foll1 is not None else None
        prec_xpos = prec1.get('xpos') if prec1 is not None else None
        

        fol_form = None

        if foll1 is not None:
            if foll1.tag == "tok":
                fol_form = foll1.text
            elif foll1.tag == "dtok":
                fol_form = foll1.get("form")
                
        prec_form = None
        if prec1 is not None:

            if prec1.tag == "tok":
                prec_form = prec1.text
            elif prec1.tag == "dtok":
                prec_form = prec1.get("form")
                
        context = " ".join(context_list).replace(
            " ,", ",").replace(" .", ".").replace("   ", " ").replace("  ", " ")

        #print(f"Context is: {context}")
        

        llista = [
            context,
            prec_form,
            Adj,
            fol_form,
            prec_lem,
            Adj_lemma,
            fol_lem,
            prec_xpos,
            Adj_xpos,
            fol_xpos,
            tok_dtok,
            xml_file.name,
            autor,
            data,
            tipus,
            dialecte,
        ]

        writer.writerow(llista)
        results.write(f"@@@ {context} @@@\n\n")
        results.write(f"Source: {fname}\n\n\n")


for xml_file in xml_files:
    if xml_file.name.startswith("."):
        continue

    beg_extract = time.time()
    doc_root = et.parse(xml_file, parser=None).getroot()
    obra = None
    autor = None
    data = None
    tipus = None
    dialecte = None

    header = doc_root.find("header")
    if header is not None:
        for el in header:
            if el.get("type") == "obra":
                obra = el.text
            elif el.get("type") == "autor":
                autor = el.text
            elif el.get("type") == "data":
                data = el.text
            elif el.get("type") == "tipologia":
                tipus = el.text
            elif el.get("type") == "dialecte":
                dialecte = el.text

    xml_extract(doc_root, xml_file.name)

    times.write(f"Time to extract {xml_file.name}: {time.time() - beg_extract}s\n")

elapsed = time.time() - beg_main
times.write(f"\n \n The end: The whole process took {elapsed}s\n")

print("Execution time:", elapsed, "seconds")
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, insist upon "**minimal**"…

Comment: I don't know the `"\x{0D}"` syntax  however `"\x0D"` is the same as `"\r"` i.e. `␍` (U+000D,  *Carriage Return (CR)*). See also https://www.editpadpro.com/tricklinebreak.html

Comment: Thanks @JosepfZ . Believe me that if I could I would produce a more minimal example. But this is the problem. This odd problem only happens when I use parallelization in the way I do it here. So, it is something that has to do with the interaction of libraries. As I said, I don't have any problems with the second script. As far as I can see, however, there are no differences in the way the csv files are written. The hope is that someone who's really good at this can check the code in its complexity and detect the problem.

Comment: I see incremental file writes/appends being the source of some latency. Specifically, I think you're doing too much file opening/writing in the `for el in matching_toks` loop, and that could be part of the original slowdown. Then you do that in parallel and it's easy for me to **imagine** (I don't know, I've only spent the last 10 minutes reading your code, not running it) getting bad writes to the CSV from concurrent processes. Try to make `xml_extract()` return the results you need, then open files once and write everything.

Comment: In general, I've found (trying to help folks out here on SO) that opening a CSV file for appending is an anti-pattern... and usually a symptom of some other problem in the code. If you can steer away from that by rethinking/restructuring you might solve the latency, which will preclude you from trying to do things in parallel. And you seem to be writing a log for every matching tok in every file, that will add latency too.

Comment: Thanks for your insightful comments Zach. I have much to learn about coding. The logs and the progress bars were introduced in a period where I was doing a lot of debugging and monitoring. That can be taken away now. The issue of the character encoding, though, this is definitely a problem that is associated to getting bad writes to the CSV from concurrent processes.

Comment: @Zach Young I'm not sure how to implement what you are suggesting because the amount of XML documents and the length of some of these documents is huge. This is why after each XML document has gone through the results need to be written and the document closed. I don't see an easy way for all of the information from over 400 documents to be held in memory and then return it to open the csv file and text files and write.

Comment: Thanks @Zach. I just wanted to thank you and acknowledge your answer. I will try to implement your solution as soon as I can and I will report whether it works in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our little discussion in the comments, I recommend starting with something like the following.  You can open all the files once for write at the very top, then reference them whereever you need to write (not in parallel, though, just synchronously):

```py
import csv
import re
import time

from pathlib import Path

from lxml import etree as et

beg_main = time.time()

xmls_dir = Path("./xmls")
files = [e for e in xmls_dir.iterdir() if e.is_file()]
xml_files = [f for f in files if f.with_suffix(".xml")]

csv_path = Path("./my_output.csv")
csv_file = open(csv_path, "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8")
writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=";")

results_path = Path("./my_results.txt")
results = open(results_path, "w", encoding="utf-8")

times_path = Path("./my_times.txt")
times = open(times_path, "w", encoding="utf-8")

tok_path = et.XPath("//tok")

def xml_extract(doc_root, fname: str):
    all_toks = tok_path(doc_root)

    matching_toks = filter(
        lambda tok: (
            re.match(r"^[EeLl][LlOoAa][Ss]*$", "".join(tok.itertext())) is not None
            and not (tok.get("xpos").startswith("D"))
        ),
        all_toks,
    )

    for el in matching_toks:
        fake_clitic = "".join(el.itertext())
        pos = all_toks.index(el)

        RelevantPrecedingElements = all_toks[max(pos - 6, 0) : pos]

        prec1 = RelevantPrecedingElements[-1]

        RelevantFollowingElements = all_toks[pos + 1 : max(pos + 6, 1)]

        foll1 = RelevantFollowingElements[0]

        context_list = []
        context_clean = []

        for elem in RelevantPrecedingElements:
            elem_text = "".join(elem.itertext())
            assert elem_text is not None
            context_list.append(elem_text)
            context_clean.append(elem_text)

        fake_clitic = f"<{fake_clitic}>"
        fake_clitic_clean = f"{el.text}"

        context_list.append(fake_clitic)
        context_clean.append(fake_clitic_clean)

        for elem in RelevantFollowingElements:
            elem_text = "".join(elem.itertext())
            assert elem_text is not None
            context_list.append(elem_text)
            context_clean.append(elem_text)

        lema_fol = foll1.get("lemma") if foll1 is not None else None
        lema_prec = prec1.get("lemma") if prec1 is not None else None
        xpos_fol = foll1.get("xpos") if foll1 is not None else None
        xpos_prec = prec1.get("xpos") if prec1 is not None else None
        form_fol = foll1.text if foll1 is not None else None
        form_prec = prec1.text if prec1 is not None else None

        context = " ".join(context_list)
        clean_context = " ".join(context_clean).replace(" ,", ",").replace(" .", ".")

        llista = [
            context,
            lema_prec,
            xpos_prec,
            form_prec,
            fake_clitic,
            lema_fol,
            xpos_fol,
            form_fol,
        ]

        writer.writerow(llista)

        results.write(f"@@@ {context} @@@\n\n")
        results.write(f"{clean_context}\n\n")
        results.write(f"Source: {fname}\n\n\n")

for xml_file in xml_files:
    if xml_file.name.startswith("."):
        continue

    beg_extract = time.time()
    doc_root = et.parse(xml_file, parser=None).getroot()
    xml_extract(doc_root, xml_file.name)

    times.write(f"Time to extract {xml_file.name}: {time.time() - beg_extract}s\n")

elapsed = time.time() - beg_main
times.write(f"\n \n The end: The whole process took {elapsed}s\n")

print("Execution time:", elapsed, "seconds")
```

When the program exits, Python will close the files for you, so you don't need all the `with open(...)` and the indentation.

I ran this version and your version on the 16 XML files you shared.

On my machine that makes some difference over opening the files inside extract_xml.  Mine runs about in about 80% the time as (20% faster than?) yours.  I have dual-channel SSDs though, so my read/writes are fast.  If you don't have that kind of hardware, opening/writing/closing will take longer.  I don't know if it's enough to see the slowdown you experienced, though.  To process all 16 files in the ZIP you shared, mine ran in 0.0055 seconds, and yours ran in only 0.0066 seconds.  Also, in my trials I found that just commenting out your print/debug statements saved time too.

Try out my code on the sample XMLs you shared and see what it runs in compared to yours.

As for the weird write error, you'll **always** get that with multiple agents trying to write at once.  If you really want/need to pursue parallelism, you'll need to figure out how to sync the writes so only one process at a time tries/can write to any one file... which might defeat the whole reason you wanted to parallelize in the first place.

Lemme know how this turns out for you. Good luck!

Comment: I edited my OP to add my adaptation of your script. Good news is that without parallelization there are no character encoding problems. Bad news is that even though your script is slightly faster with the sample files when I tried it with a more representative sample of XML documents it became rather slow. In particular it strugled with a 32MB XML file. Unfortunately, there are quite a few of those. Perhaps I did something wrong when adapting your code but it is still slower than I need it to be. I'll keep on looking. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @jfontana, hey glad it helped at least a little. I can’t see that you’ve quantified how slow this process can be. How long does it take to process that 32 MB file? To root out the slow parts of the process you’ll probably need to get into profiling. If you want more help along that line you’ll need to create a new question (since you’ve marked this answer as accepted it likely won’t get anyone’s attention). I recommend investigating Python’s profiling options, and then asking a new question specifically about that if you get stuck. Also, how often do you have to run this whole process?

Comment: Hi @Zach and thanks again for your help. You are right about the need for a new question. I run processes similar to this rather often. This is the info on processing times.

Time to extract C-08.xml: 38.22333073616028s
Time to extract H-21.xml: 0.04310774803161621s
Time to extract H-22.xml: 0.014403820037841797s
Time to extract H-23.xml: 0.01652812957763672s
Time to extract A-02.xml: 16850.478314876556s
Time to extract H-24.xml: 2.7126471996307373s

 
 The end: The whole process took 16891.538549900055s
 
  The 32 MB file is A-02.xml the next one in size is C-08.xml with 4,6MB.

Comment: @jfontana, wow! 4 hours for A-02.xml?! Can you share that file? You have A-02_potineig.xml in that Dropbox ZIP, but it's only 9 KB. I'd really like to see where all that time is going. Thanks.

Comment: @jfontana, I profiled your code and found a really bad culprit for chewing up time. I cannot guarantee it will take that 4 hour process down to 10 minutes, but it might. I wrote up my findings in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/zacharysyoung/79c29599e1ec8ae9ab6df9c9ea61cc71).

Comment: @jfontana, thought of a better (and even slightly faster) approach, updated the above gist.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't see this earlier. After I posted my last comment I got on to other things and I didn't check whether there were new postings. I just saw the notification doing some clean up of my e-mail queue. Anyway, here's the linke to the file that was taking so long to process:

https://www.dropbox.com/home/Public/A-02.xml.zip

Comment: Thank you SO much for the gist with the explanation. For me an explanation is even more valuable than a practical solution so you really made my day.

Comment: @jfontana, great! I'm really glad the gist helped explain things. Did it also help things run faster? I tried downloading that XML you just posted in the comment, but Dropbox says it doesn't exist.

Comment: Try with this link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k0lzq9tv5fi7jvv/A-02.xml.zip?dl=0 This one should work. I just tried your alternative code this morning with the A-02.xml file. The results are:

ran op_extract in 43s

ran my_extract_index in 0.68s

Pretty spectacular difference when you think with the previous version it was: Time to extract A-02.xml: 16850.478314876556s